# Generate video from script (concat and simple effects)

Tags: linux, video, automation, video-processing

I am looking for a tool that is somewhat like a "TeX for videos".

Some features I would dream about:

- a text file as input
- concatenate videos by filename
- video effects like blur, saturation and so on
- include text and simple elements like colored boxes
- output a single complete H.264 file after generation step

Is there anything built on ffmpeg or html5 perhaps?

This would be very useful for making branded videos (e.g. for YouTube) in a consistent quality.

Comment: _"I am looking for a tool"_ then use Google search since that makes it [**off-topic (see point 4)**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you know of FFmpeg then why not just use that, since it does all the above listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avisynth gets you probably most of it: 
http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page